# Windows cmd prompt move file

Tags: windows, file, file-io, cmd, directory

I'm learning the windows command prompt, and I typed in move file.txt /file. when in c:\dir.

file.txt completely disappear. Any idea where it went, or did is it deleted?

```
>C:\
>>\dir
>>>\file
>>\dir2
>>>\file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in modern DOS shells `/` is already recognized as an alternative path separator to `\` when passing as arguments. Test shows that your file was moved as if you ran:

```
move file.txt \file
```

Which means to move `file.txt` to the root directory of the current drive and name it as `file` granting `\file` is not an existing directory. If `C:` is your current drive, it should now exist as

```
c:\file
```

From `move /?`:

> [drive:][path]filename1
>
> Specifies the location and name of the file or files you want to move.
>
> destination
>
> Specifies the new location of the file. Destination can consist of a drive letter and colon, a directory name, or a combination. If you are moving only one file, you can also include a filename if you want to rename the file when you move it.

Comment: If it didn't create a c:\file directory then it was just deleted?

Comment: no, if no `c:\file` directory happend to exist, your file now is named `file`(without extension) and resides in `c:\ `

Comment: I'm saying if the directory file doesn't exist in the C:\ root, the c:\dir, c:\dir\file or c:\file (non-existent), where might it exist?

Comment: @JosephCasey If before operation a directory named `C:\file` did not exist, your file can only exist now as `C:\file`. `move` can't do any other kind of behaviour. I doubt that it moved the file to other places or that it deleted the file.

Comment: if no `c:\file` DIRECTORY happend to exist BEFORE, your file now is named `file` (without extension) and resides in `c:\ `. Try `type c:\file`

Comment: @JosephCasey Try to emulate the behavior again by recreating the file `C:\dir\file.txt` and running the operation `move file.txt /file` in `C:\dir`. If it works as we explained, then it means you have done something different before.

Comment: @Stephan has it right. I was looking for a File Type: File Folder and didn't look for the \file dir to be created as a file. Does this mean file.txt never got created, or is it somehow coded in 'file' without an extension.

Comment: @JosephCasey That's same file renamed without the extension. `move` never creates a directory however if a directory exists, the target would be moved to that directory instead.

Comment: @konsolebox is right: the `c:\file` IS your file. You can see it with `type c:\file` and can give it it's old name with `rename c:\file c:\file.txt`

Comment: You might have had the impression that files should always have an extension (`.something`) but that's not case. Having an extension or not having an extension is possible both with files and directories; although `.something` can't really be technically called as an extension when it comes to directories.